# powershell share permission level on a folder

Tags: powershell-2.0

Have some problems with setting share permissions to folder.
Cant understand in which mode to set permission to a User Domain\User

1. `NET SHARE testfolder=C:\test /GRANT:Everyone,FULL` set NTFS permission but not share permission to folder
2. Using [wmiClass] "Win32-Share".create() also do the same (write NTFS permissions)

How to set Users to share with folder?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "in which mode"? Why are you granting permissions to **Everyone** with **NET SHARE** if you say you want to grant permissions to **Domain\User**?  "Using [wmiClass] "Win32-Share".create()" is also very vague. In which way are you trying to use the WMI method? (Show the command you're using and specify where/how you're invoking it)

Comment: I am using win32_Share.create() in next function:

Answer (score 0):

I am using win32_Share.create() in next function:

function shareFolder 
{
    Param ($folder, $uname)
    $name = $folder.Name
    $path = $folder.Fullname

```
$sd = ([WMIClass] "Win32_SecurityDescriptor").CreateInstance()

$ace = ([WMIClass] "Win32_ACE").CreateInstance()
$Trustee = ([WMIClass] "Win32_Trustee").CreateInstance()
$Trustee.Name = $uname
$Trustee.Domain = $null
$ace.AccessMask = 524288
$ace.AceFlags = 3 
$ace.AceType = 0 
$ACE.Trustee = $Trustee 
$sd.DACL += $ace.psObject.baseobject 

$mc = [WmiClass]"Win32_Share"
$InParams = $mc.psbase.GetMethodParameters("create")
$InParams.Access = $sd
$InParams.Description = "Share"
$InParams.MaximumAllowed = $Null
$InParams.Name = "test"
$InParams.Password = $Null
$InParams.Path = $folder 
$InParams.Type = [uint32]0

$mc.PSBase.InvokeMethod("Create", $InParams, $Null)
```

}

shareFolder "C:\test" "admin"

In this case as i had understood, ntfs permissions are setting up.
How to set 'share permission' on folder (read/write)?